# Modify reverse polish notation calculator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to modify this reverse polish notation calculator. I've done nearly all of it, but it's not printing the way I want and I can't figure out why. The source code is:

```
def op_pow(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a ** b)
def op_mul(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a * b)
def op_div(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a / b)
def op_add(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a + b)
def op_sub(stack):
    b = stack.pop(); a = stack.pop()
    stack.append(a - b)
def op_num(stack, num):
    stack.append(num)

ops = {
 '^': op_pow,
 '*': op_mul,
 '/': op_div,
 '+': op_add,
 '-': op_sub,
 }

def get_input(inp):
    tokens = inp.strip().split()
    return tokens

def rpn_calc(tokens):
    stack = []
    table = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token in ops:
            ops[token](stack)
            table.append( (token, ' '.join(str(s) for s in stack)) )
        else:
            op_num(stack, eval(token))
            table.append( (token, ' '.join(str(s) for s in stack)) )
    return table

rp = rpn_calc(get_input((raw_input())))

print rp
```

So if I input:

```
5 5 +
```

then the output is:

```
[('5', '5'), ('5', '5 5'), ('+', '10')]
```

and ideally I want the output to be just:

```
 10
```

I think the brackets might be there because it's in a list but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table looks like it stores a list containing the evolving state. Instead of returning table from your rpn_calc function, it sounds like you want to just return the top of the stack.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I've managed to remove the brackets by changing `print rp` to `for item in rp:
  print item[0], ', '.join(map(str, item[1:]))` which has fixed that. It's now just printing, like you said, the evolving state.

Comment: How about `return stack[-1]` instead of `return table`?

Comment: Thanks so much! If you don't mind me asking, i've got one more quick question. Is it possible to change it so that instead of entering the numbers all on the same line like, ` 5 5 +` can I make it so you can type a number, then enter, then a number the next line, then enter and the operand, then the = sign and it will give me the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: To do that you would want to retain the stack between calls to rpn_calc, i.e., don't set `stack = []` every time you call rpn_calc.